# MongoDB - What is the privilege needed to run setFeatureCompatibilityVersion?

Tags: mongodb

Using mongoDB 3.4.3 I'm facing the problem described in this issue (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26556) when trying to create an index with collation.

Since I've upgraded from a previous version, it says what is needed is to explicitly allow the backwards-incompatible 3.4 features set, but with a user with role `userAdminAnyDatabase` I still have no permission:

```
> db.adminCommand({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4"})
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command {setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: \"3.4\" }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

My question is, what role does the user needs to be able to do this?

Comment: Is that a typo in userAdminAnyDatabse role ?

Comment: yes, thanks @Veeram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a user with `root` privilege worked.

After authentication:

```
> use admin
> db.adminCommand({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4"})
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by a user with root privilege? A linux user or a database user?

Comment: A mongo admin user

Comment: To anyone who comes along and is as confused as I was, you need to run this command on the `admin` database logged in as a db user having the `root` Role

Comment: Here is how to grant a `root` role if there is anyone wondering: `db.grantRolesToUser('admin', [{ role: 'root', db: 'admin' }])`

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to run the command as I was getting the following error :

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: \"3.4\", $db: \"admin\" }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

The following link gives details :

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159390/mongodb-all-commands-spit-out-not-authorized-on-admin-to-execute-command

Steps I followed (I am using Mac) :

1. sudo nano /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
2. Comment the security as shown below: 
   [image]
3. Restart MongoDB. sudo brew services restart mongodb
4. Connect using mongodb and run the following code

   use admin

   db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )

   [image]
5. Uncomment the security in mongod.conf and restart the MongoDB server.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to execute setFeatureCompatibilityVersion user must have "clusterManager" built-in role.

See documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterManager